# Is SocketAsyncEventArgs a good choice for a client application?

Tags: c#, sockets, algorithmic-trading

Is it a good solution to use **SocketAsyncEventArgs** for a Client application receiving market quotes ? Or a traditional while(true) is better ?

I am looking for the fastest solution in order to receive thousand of messages per second.

Comment: How many incoming connections will there be open? I believe asynchronous networking is only faster when handling massive numbers of concurrent connections, to handle high traffic on a single connection you'll have to parallelise elsewhere.

Comment: There is a good CodeProject article here- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketasynceventargs.aspx, recommend you read it

Comment: I will have 1 connection. Max 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For high volume messaging, `SocketAsyncEventArgs` is best. MS did a lot of work to make the API as light on memory thrashing as possible, so GC will need to fire much less often than with other approaches. IIRC it's the only API Silverlight supports, so if that's a possibility then it's your only option.

Comment: Even for a client ? All example on MSDN are for server side.